# App timeout when not touch screen after x time

Tags: android, timeout, touchscreen

I am trying to create a lock screen when user does not touch the screen(inactive). After 30 sec I lock custom screen and I want the user to re-login but when user login the app must open before current screen. As like windows lock screen. Any one can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the solution

Overide the below method

```
long lastActivity ;
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    lastActivity = new Date().getTime();
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

In onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    long now = new Date().getTime();
    if ((now - lastActivity) > Your logout  Value) {
       // do your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can I use this methot in  base activity for all my activity

Comment: you can do in BaseActivity class.

Comment: When I override motot app is not startin g